# WHERE statement that selects everything (content and NULL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you return all possibilities, whether there is content or it is NULL?

If I want to return everything that isn't NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%'
```

And if I  want to return all NULLs:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS NULL
```

How do I combine them both? I need to be able to because I am parameterizing it. The front end of my application will have multiple options ALL (any content or NULL) or a specific value.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Let me clarify better. I have a dropdown List that will show things like this

-Select All-
Team A
Team B
...

So if -Select All- is selected then I need the query to return all NULLs and those with any Team

If Team A is selected I need to show only Team A and no NULLs and so on...

I cant change the query just a single variable (parameter)

Comment: Umm.. for ALL *don't* use any criteria?

Comment: The above is just an example. I am actually dealing with a long and complex query and there has to be a parameter because I'll be passing it via C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward. To only get NULLS:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column IS NULL
```

To only get NOT NULLS:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE column IS NOT NULL
-- could be this if your example is not representative
-- WHERE column IS NULL OR column LIKE '%whatever%'
```

And for everything (no filter), just do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

**Further clarification:**

In your example, if the code is already written and you can only pass in the WHERE clause then you could do this:

```
WHERE <insert here>

column IS NULL -- just nulls
column = 'teamX' OR column IS NULL -- nulls or 'teamX'
column IS NOT NULL -- any value, but no nulls
1=1 -- for the case where you don't really want a WHERE clause. All records
```

It doesn't sound like this is the best way of structuring your code, but if you are already restricted by something that can't be changed, I guess you have to make do.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE column LIKE '%' OR column IS NULL
```

Comment: It's funny how the same answers get upvoted in one place and downvoted elsewhere

Comment: Does this mean anything other than `Querying without WHERE clause`? This is an unnecessary hit, isn't it?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter not sure if funny. I'm not sure if you are implying something, but the **only** downvoted answer that I see was using an `AND` before. And it wasn't my downvote anyway. And, not sure if it matters, but apparently my answer was posted first, so that may influence why I got upvotes

Comment: @Kaf Not in this case, but as OP said on a comment, he needs it for another situation than the one posted

Comment: @Lamak no, I am not implying that you're going and downvoting all other answers :) Just noticing the trend.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter still "downvoted elsewhere" seems like an exaggeration since only one answer had been downvoted

Comment: @Lamak "elsewhere" doesn't nessesery mean "many". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elsewhere

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I know what it means. Though I have a hard time believing that **that's** what you meant

Comment: @Ambrose I answered so the user could have his solution. Later, when multiple answers were already posted, I voted to close since it really is a trivial question. I should've posted my answer as a comment really, or just vote to close I think

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `NULL` as the parameter value means "All"

```
WHERE Team = @Team OR @Team IS NULL
```

Unless you are on 2008+ **and** use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` this can give sub optimal plans though.

See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question then this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column LIKE '%' or column Is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `select * from table` get you what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean "*parameter can be passed or parameter can be NULL*" ?

If so then something like this should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE param IS NULL OR column LIKE '%' + param '%'
```

Similarly if parameter passed keyword 'ALL' that means "select everything" it would be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE param = 'All' OR column LIKE '%' + param '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

One case is not to use any where clauses.

Or else you can use or condition

```
where (column is null or column like '%something%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%'
Union
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IS NULL
```

It will combine both query if they have the same column name and number, since the only difference is where clause, it should be working